# How to loop over display numbers in .xprofile?

Tags: x11, video, xrandr, display, edid

Is there a simple command to get all the **display numbers** (and *only* the display numbers) connected to the computer? The use case is that I'd like to have separate colour profiles `~/.color/icc/${display}.icc` for each display `$display`, and I'd like to [load](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ICC_Profiles#Xinitrc_Example_2) each one which is available during X startup using `/usr/bin/dispwin -d ${display} ~/.color/icc/${display}.icc`. [Current `.xprofile` code](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/4c7839e96da920f39fc866877cac317e07fe8ed9/.xprofile#L29-L34):

```
monitor_color_profile="${HOME}/.color/icc/monitor.icc"
if [ -f "$monitor_color_profile" ]
then
    /usr/bin/dispwin "$monitor_color_profile"
fi
unset monitor_color_profile
```

I'm already using [`xrandr` to get display sizes](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/4c7839e96da920f39fc866877cac317e07fe8ed9/.screenlayout/monitor_resolutions.sh).

Comment: What does the input look like (in `.xprofile`)?

Comment: I misunderstood: disregard...

Comment: It's deep, man, but `xauth list` looks promising... I dunno if they'll all be there though, or if they must all be active. But it prints a list. There's also some XDMCP stuff that could probably do it, but that's all disabled by default. Maybe have a look in `man Xsecurity` - I haven't looked at it but the two `man` pages with useful information in which I did look both point there. Oh, and, if you're really lucky, you can get it with `xdotool search *(something)*`...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Why would you want to affect anything but the display that X is starting on in your X session startup script?

Comment: @Gilles: I have one or more displays per computer. Each display may or may not have a corresponding colour profile. I want to assign the colour profiles which exist to the corresponding display.

Comment: @l0b0 Ah, are you trying to obtain the output names (`VGA1`, `HDMI2`, …), and not the display numbers (`:0`, `:1`, …)? That would make more sense. Since you know about `xrandr` already, why don't you parse its output?

Comment: @Gilles I need whatever is used as input to `dispwin`, which `dispwin` calls "displays". I doubt it makes sense to tie a colour profile to a cable connector...

Comment: @l0b0 It doesn't make sense to tie a color profile to an X display number, since these are assigned dynamically! I'm not familiar with `dispwin`; from reading the [manual](http://www.argyllcms.com/doc/dispwin.html) it appears that the argument to `-d` is not an X11 display number (unlike the argument to `-display`), but some other concept that's specific to this software. What does `dispcal --` show?

Comment: @Gilles It just shows the program usage info.